# Distance between plane and ball

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I need to find the shortest distance between the plane $\ x-3y+2z+5=0 $ and a ball with center point at $\ (5,-14,9) $ and with radius of $\ 12 $

So to my understanding the ball equation will be $\ (x-5)^2 + (y+14)^2 + (z-9)^2 = 1 $ and the perpendicular vector of the plane is $\ (1,-3,2) $ (My guess is that the shortest path to the ball must be perpendicular, am I correct??)  so it should be some $\ t(1,-3,2) $

My guess is that I should just derive the formula of distance between some point $\ P $ and the plane which is $\ \frac{x_0 -3 y_0 +2z_0 +5}{\sqrt{1^2+(-3)^2+2^2}} $ and check when it equals $\ 0 $ ? but I'm not sure how to actually do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First compute the distance of the plane from the center of the sphere.

$$d_O = \frac{|5-3(-14)+2(9)+5|}{\sqrt{1^2+3^2+2^2}}=\frac{70}{\sqrt{14}}=5\sqrt{14}.$$

After which, we have to take the radius into consideration.

$$5\sqrt{14}-12$$

Answer (score 2):

Normal of plane: $(1,-3,2)$;

Normalized(of unit length):

$\vec{n} =(\sqrt{14})^{-1}(1,-3,2)$.

Line through center of ball with direction vector $\vec{n}$:

$\vec {r}=$

$ (5,-14,9)+t (\sqrt{14})^{-1}(1,-3,2)$.

Point of intersection with plane:

$5-3(-14) +2(9) + $

$t(\sqrt{14})^{-1}(1 +9+4)+5=0.$

$65+t\sqrt{14}+5=0;$

$t= -70(\sqrt{14})^{-1}=-5\sqrt{14};$

Min. distance to sphere : $5\sqrt{14} -12$.

Note: $|t|$ is the distance from center of ball to plane.

Comment: Why In the last equation is once normized an once not?

Comment: Alexander. I do not understand. Can you rephrase?

Comment: I am sorry, I got confused. You are just plugging in the point along the radius of the sphere in the equation of the plane. that makes sense.

Comment: No worry, it is exactly as you say.

Answer (score 1):

By your idea the answer is $$\frac{|5+42+18+5|}{\sqrt{1^2+(-3)^2+2^2}}-12=5\sqrt{14}-12.$$

Answer (score 1):

We can also take help from calculus here. For any point (x,y,z) on the plane the distance square is $f(x,y,z) = (x-5)^2 + (y+14)^2 + (z-9)^2$ and we need to minimize this. Now from equation of plane we get $x = 3y-2z-5$, putting the value of x in above function we get

$f(y,z) = (3y-2z-10)^2 + (y+14)^2 + (z-9)^2$

differentiating wrt $y$ and setting it to zero we get

$6(3y-2z-10) + 2(y+14) = 0$

differentiating wrt $z$ and setting it to zero we get

$-4(3y-2z-10) + 2(z-9) = 0$

Simplifying the above two equations and solving for $y,z$ we get $y=1,z=-1$, putting these values back to $x = 3y-2z-5$ we get $x=0$, so the point on the plane is $(0,1,-1)$ for which the distance is minimum. Now for distance, $(x-5)^2 + (y+14)^2 + (z-9)^2 = 25+225+100 = 350$, so the distance is $\sqrt{350} = 5\sqrt{14}$

This is from the center of the ball and you subtract the radius of the ball from this. The advantage of this is you also get the point on the plane along with distance.